# Good practice for "Updates"?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a CSV with data:

```
 ID, Name, Address, Date
 1 , Paul, Fake 123,2017-01-01
```

I upload that file to a new table (i.e.: "Users")

After several months, I recieve a CSV with Inserts AND Updates of that table. i.e.

```
 ID, Name, Address, Date
 1 , Paul, Fake 999,2017-06-01
 2 , Joe , Foo 123 ,2017-06-01
 ...
```

If it was a common SQL database, I did an Upsert (like Replace in Mysql). But what is the best pattern to do this in BigQuery? The DML quota limit for updates is 96 per table, too small for this :(.

I thought in a "transactional" table, and a "final" table.

When I have a new file, I can upload to the Transactional table. After that, I can execute a query, obtaining the last value for each "ID", and put that data in the "Final" table. Obviously, the query has the option "writeDisposition: WRITE_TRUNCATE" to erase old data.

I think that this a messy solution, but I can't found a better way. Someone knows how to do this better? There is any place to read "design patterns" for BigQuery?

Comment: I'm hoping someone else can write a complete answer, but a common solution is to have an append-only table along with a logical view for each day. For the current day, the logical view selects the most recent value in each dimension. At the end of the day, run an update query to fix the duplicates, then change the logical view to be just `SELECT *` for that day. Make sure to use standard SQL for your view definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few notes,

- I am assuming that the change in data is large enough relative to the target data to overwrite the target table. For example, you would not want to follow this approach if you have a few hundred change records for a target table with a billion records.
- Also, query might require some changes for the partitioned table.
- As a side effect this will remove any duplicate records from the target table. So you need to carefully choose the columns that are used to identify the change in record.

Using Joins and a landing table:

Let's call table with change data Source that needs to be merged to Target Table.

```
SELECT SRC.Id as Id,
       SRC.Name as Name,
       SRC.Address as Address,
       SRC.Date as Date
FROM SourceTable SRC 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TargetTable TGT
USING (Id)
WHERE TGT.Id IS NULL

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT CASE WHEN (SRC.Id IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Name IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Address IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Date IS NOT NULL) THEN SRC.Id ELSE TGT.Id END AS Id,
       CASE WHEN (SRC.Id IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Name IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Address IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Date IS NOT NULL) THEN SRC.Name ELSE TGT.Name END AS Name,
       CASE WHEN (SRC.Id IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Name IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Address IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Date IS NOT NULL) THEN SRC.Address ELSE TGT.Address END AS Address,
       CASE WHEN (SRC.Id IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Name IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Address IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Date IS NOT NULL) THEN SRC.Date ELSE TGT.Date END AS Date
FROM SourceTable SRC 
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN TargetTable TGT
USING (Id)
```

Now, you can run above query with WRITE_TRUNCATE on Target Table.
I have not tested this particular query, but the approach is good. Complexity of the query could be reduced by little bit of coding or UDFs in Bigquery. Performance largely depends on the size and nature of the change data.

I hope this helps.